# EntityType has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType - but it does

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6

OK. I've searched for the solution, but none of them fit my problem.
I have an entity defined called tblRbnCampaignMemberList like so:

```
[Table("tblRbnCampaignMemberList")]
public partial class tblRbnCampaignMemberList
{
    [Key]
    public int rcm_id { get; set; }
    public int rcm_MemberUID { get; set; }
    public int rcm_rp_id { get; set; }
    public int rcm_rc_id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? rcm_InterviewCompletedUTC { get; set; }
    public int rcm_quality_id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? rcm_Rbn_claim_date { get; set; }
    public int rcm_Rbn_status_id { get; set; }
    public int rcm_QC_MemberUID { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "smallmoney")]
    public decimal? rcm_AwardAmount { get; set; }
    public int? rcm_AwardTypeID { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string rcm_RbnOrderID { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? rcm_DateAwarded { get; set; }
    public int? rcm_AwardedBy_MemberUID { get; set; }
    [StringLength(1024)]
    public string rcm_Comments { get; set; }
    public bool rcm_Canceled { get; set; }
    public int? rcm_new_rcm_id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string rcm_AlternateEmail { get; set; }
    public virtual tblRbnAwardType tblRbnAwardType { get; set; }
    public virtual tblRbnCampaign tblRbnCampaign { get; set; }
    public virtual tblRbnQuality tblRbnQuality { get; set; }
    public virtual tblRbnGiftclaimStatu tblRbnGiftclaimStatu { get; set; }
    public virtual tblRbnProject tblRbnProject { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have another class defined from the first one like so:

```
public class smc_RbnCampaignMemberList : Entities.tblRbnCampaignMemberList
{
     public String sml_Title { get; set; }
     public int rcme_MemberUID { get; set; }
     public String rcme_firstName { get; set; }
     public String rcme_middleName { get; set; }
     public String rcme_lastName { get; set; }
     public String rcme_eMail { get; set; }
     public String rcme_orgName { get; set; }
     public String rcme_tmpei_idValue { get; set; }
     public int rcme_qualityAvg { get; set; }
     public int AMMember { get; set; }
     public int DBMember { get; set; }
     public int LPMember { get; set; }
     public int SBMember { get; set; }
     public int AEMember { get; set; }

     public List<smc_RbnMemberTags> lstRbnMemberTags { get; set; }
}
```

The compiler is happy as a clam, however when I try to run the project, I get a runtime error that says:

> EntityType 'smc_RbnCampaignMemberTags' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

The rutime error happens even though the code isn't even using that type and even though there IS a public `[Key]` defined.

Thoughts?

Comment: What's your core for `smc_RbnCampaignMemberTags'`?

Answer (score 0):

The answer in this case was not to inherit from an entity framework class. I tried using the [NotMapped] tag on the inheriting class, but no dice.  I bit the bullet and re-defined the inheriting class to just be the same as the base class and the issue went away.  There really should be some way to inherit the data structure of an Entity Framework class without all the attending tracking, etc that causes this error.

On to the next bug.